# What Python bindings are there for CVS or SVN?

Tags: python, svn, version-control, cvs

I once did a cursory search and found no good CVS bindings for Python.  I wanted to be able to write helper scripts to do some fine-grained manipulation of the repository and projects in it.  I had to resort to using `popen` and checking `stdout` and `stderr` and then parsing those.  It was messy and error-prone.

Are there any good quality modules for CVS integration for Python?  Which module do you prefer and why?

While I am at it, is there a good Subversion integration module for Python?  My understanding is that Subversion has a great API for such things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For cvs, [pyCVS](http://pycvs.sourceforge.net/) may be worth a look.

For svn, there is [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/), which is pretty good.

Comment: Are you aware of any easy way to access svn from 64-bit Python on Windows x64?

Answer (score 1):

[Tailor](http://progetti.arstecnica.it/tailor), a Python program which lets different version control systems interoperate, simply calls the external programs `cvs` and `svn` when working with repositories of those formats.  This seems pretty ugly, but reduces Tailor's dependencies from "requires ____ bindings" to "requires working system".